# Atomically update 2 Long values

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, atomicinteger

Let's say I have the following class in Java:

```
class Record {
  
  String name;
  double count;
  long repeat;
  
  public Record(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public synchronized void update(Record other){
    this.count = (other.count * other.repeat + this.count * this.repeat)/(other.repeat + this.repeat);
    this.repeat = this.repeat + other.repeat;
  }
```

Now I have a map of such records `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Record> recordConcurrentHashMap;`

and I want to create a thread-safe correct update function.

Currently I have done this:

```
static ConcurrentHashMap<String,Record> recordConcurrentHashMap;

public static void updateRecords(Record other){
    Record record = recordConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(other.name, Record::new);
    record.update(other);
}
```

I am having to keep the `update` function synchronized to achieve correctness.

Can I do this without `synchronized` using `LongAdder` or `LongAccumulator`?

I tried using those, but couldn't figure out how to achieve the complex calculation with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't, certainly not with those.

What you might consider doing -- which would avoid the `synchronized` -- would be to make `Record` immutable and unmodifiable, and do something like

```
class Record {
  final String name;
  final double count;
  final long repeat;

  public Record(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  private Record(String name, double count, long repeat) {
    this.name = name; this.count = count; this.repeat = repeat;
  }

  public Record combine(Record other){
    return new Record(
      name,
      other.count * other.repeat + this.count * this.repeat)
         /(other.repeat + this.repeat),
      repeat + other.repeat);
  }
}

public static void updateRecords(Record other){
  Record record = recordConcurrentHashMap.merge(
    other.name, other, Record::combine);
}
```

Comment: Does it have to immutable, since merge is atomic?  Can't merge call combine and return one of the Record's updated to occupy the map value?  Can't the other Record be reused?

Comment: Yes, it does need to be immutable; otherwise multiple merges on the same record could race and even cause nonsensical output -- in the absence of the lock, which the point was to eliminate.  (Note, for example, that `merge` may call the method multiple times in the event of contention, so you might end up combining the values twice!)